# Upload files to share point using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, file-upload

I'm trying to upload files to a folder using SharePoint and C#.

I managed to create folders with my code and it works fine.

This is my Document class:

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public class Document
{
    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }

    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public bool ReplaceExisting { get; set; }

    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public string Folder { get; set; }

    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }

    public Document()
    {
        Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public Document(string name, byte[] content)
    {
        Name = name;
        ReplaceExisting = false;
        Content = content;
        Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public Document(string name, byte[] content, bool replace)
    {
        Name = name; 
        Content = content;
        ReplaceExisting = replace;
        Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
}
```

And this is the class where I use it to upload files (Document) to an existing share point folder:

```
public class SharePointHandler : IDisposable
{
    private static string sharePointSite = "My Site";
    private static string documentLibraryName = "Root folder";

    public SharePointHandler() { }

    public void Upload(List<Document> documents, string company, int year, string quarter)
    {
        string Year = year.ToString();

        try
        {
            using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(sharePointSite))
            {
                var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibraryName);
                context.Load(list);

                var root = list.RootFolder;
                context.Load(root);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                .
                .
                .

                foreach (var document in documents)
                {
                    var fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
                    fileCreationInformation.Content = document.Content;

                    fileCreationInformation.Overwrite = true;

                    fileCreationInformation.Url = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + company + "/" + Year + "/" + quarter + "/" + document.Name;
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = quarterFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);


                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> property in document.Properties)
                        uploadFile.ListItemAllFields[property.Key] = property.Value;


                    try
                    {
                        uploadFile.CheckOut();
                        context.ExecuteQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                    uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
                    context.ExecuteQuery();

                    uploadFile.CheckIn("", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            return;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

When I run the code I have one document with:

Content: {byte[11430]}

Folder: null

Name: Testing.docx

Properties: Count = 0

ReplaceExisting: false

Everything works fine and I get the URL needed.
But when I get to these commands:

```
try
{
    uploadFile.CheckOut();
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

The program falls and I get error that says: File not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried creating an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I can't do it in MVC, it's in my work place.

Comment: You are getting an error because you are trying to checkout the file before you upload it.  Since it doesn't exist yet, it fails.  Just remove uploadFile.CheckOut(); and it will work fine.  If you want to replace an existing document you need to find that file via a query and then replace its byte[] content if you want to use CheckOut.

Comment: I removed uploadFile.CheckOut(); and it still falls and says File not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of an upload to SharePoint via CSOM:

```
using (ClientContext conext = new ClientContext(site.url))
{
    List projectFiles = projects.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Project Files");
    context.Load(projectFiles.RootFolder, w => w.ServerRelativeUrl);                       
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    FileStream documentStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath);
    byte[] info = new byte[documentStream.Length];
    documentStream.Read(info, 0, (int)documentStream.Length);

    string fileURL = projectFiles.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Folder/FileName.ext";

    FileCreationInformation fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
    fileCreationInformation.Overwrite = true;
    fileCreationInformation.Content = info;
    fileCreationInformation.Url = fileURL;
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = projectFiles.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);
    context.Load(uploadFile, w => w.MajorVersion, w => w.MinorVersion);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

In your case, I would upload the file and ExecuteQuery() and then add your metadata and execute a second query, make sure you add a context.Load after your files.Add().  You are trying to do too many things at once, so just use this code to get the file uploaded and work your way through your other needs after.  Also, the file add will not create folders for you so make sure you are specifying a valid path.